# I'm having trouble identifying this leaf!

Tags: identification, trees, seeds, seedlings

This was supposed to be bamboo seed, but turned out to be what appears to be a deciduous, serrated leaf bush or tree. The plants are only a year old, so not any bark to reference... The seed was long and thin like a grain of rice of brown colour. I extracted the inner part from a husk and they grew well. Looked very similar to bamboo seeds. Leaf size is about 3-4inch length. Don't  worry, I got my money back, but wasn't able to find out what it is. Thanks if you can help :) [image: looks like an elm but seed doesn't]